# Remove letters from string

Tags: pandas, string

I'm trying to remove single letters in a string column database. I Install pandas 2.2.1.

Input: ['X ABCD X X WEB X']
Output: ['ABCD WEB']

this is the code I try but input is exactly as output

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=['X ABCD X X WEB X'], columns=['c1'])
print (df), '\n'
df.c1 = df.c1.str.replace(r'\b\w\b', '').str.replace(r'\s+', ' ')
print (df)
```

Answer (score 0):

just add regex=True

`df.c1 = df.c1.str.replace(r'\b\w\b', '',regex=True).str.replace(r'\s+', ' ',regex=True)`